# Override :INITFORM of the class slot in subclass

Tags: common-lisp, clos

I need to slightly generalize the default slot value in the subclass.

Example:

```
(defclass class-a ()
  ((slot-1 :initarg :slot-1 :initform #'identity)
   <...> other-slots<...>))
```

Its subclass is

```
(defclass class-b (class-a)
  ((slot-2 :initarg :slot-2 :initform 0)))
```

But `#'IDENTITY` is not good enough as the default value, slightly more general

```
(lambda (&rest x) x)
```

will suit better as it expect multiple arguments (I think it doesn't contradict Liskov principle). What is the best way to override `:INITFORM` for `CLASS-B`?

1. I can add `INITIALIZE-INSTANCE :AFTER` for `CLASS-B` and see if `SLOT-1` is set to `#'IDENTITY` and override it.
2. What happens if I reintroduce `SLOT-1` in `CLASS-B`? I would want to avoid it as I would have to repeat all the slot information for it.

Comment: You should be able to just add `SLOT1` with only the new `:INITFORM` in the subclass (no need to repeat anything else). According to the [spec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/07_ec.htm), the most specific initform is used.

Comment: See also default-initargs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What happens if I reintroduce SLOT-1 in CLASS-B?

It works.

> I would want to avoid it as I would have to repeat all the slot information for it.

No. Only the difference.

Answer (score 5):

On easy alternative is to use `:default-initargs` for the class instead of `:initform` for the slot. In that case, you just have to provide a new default-initarg for that slot in the subclass. See [Chris Riesbeck's rationale](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/academics/courses/325/readings/graham/chap11-notes.html) for `:default-initargs` and see [this lisptip](http://lisptips.com/post/11728375873/initform-and-default-initargs) for examples.

Comment: Good to know! Haven't seen `:IDEFAULT-INITARGS` before. Thanks